# Size of transfer from RAM to L3?

Tags: memory, architecture

We know that to compensate latency, the size of the block transferred from Disk to RAM is 4K (1 page). What happens between RAM and L3? Does it transfer just 1 cache line (64 bytes) or more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cache line size on an Intel Core i7 CPU of L1, L2 and L3 caches are all 64 bytes.[1] I don't believe there is a fixed number of lines that get cached at once and more dependent on predictive logic.

[1] https://www.scss.tcd.ie/Jeremy.Jones/CS3021/5%20caches.pdf